# Hacer que uno de los dos sean required

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas, me gustaria saber como podría hacer por javascript que si un campo email no está rellenado le ponga required a telefono, y viceversa

```
Tel&#233;fono:<br> <input id="inputTelf"  name="telf" type="number"  min="111111111" max="999999999" autocomplete="off">

Email:<br> <input id="inputEmail" name="email" size="20" type="email"  autocomplete="off">
```

Gracias.

Comment: quieres decir que tienen que rellenar al menos uno ?

Comment: sip eso es justo lo que necesito

Comment: en el submit del formulario no puedes hacer una comprobacion de cual de ellos está relleno y sacar un mensaje si ninguno lo está?

Comment: estás usando algún framework o js a pelo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra opción para realizar la validación:

```js
validate = function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  var tel = event.target.querySelector('#phone');
  var email = event.target.querySelector('#email');
  var validation = (tel.value.trim() && email.value.trim());
 
  // Optional
  notifyAlert(validation);

  return validation;
}

notifyAlert = function(validation) {
 var status = (validation) ? 'success' : 'error';
  alert(`Validation ${status}`);
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}
.form {margin: 1rem;}
.form__group {margin: 0 0 1rem 0;}
.form__group label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validate(event)" class="form">
<div class="form__group">
  <label for="phone">Tel&#233;fono:</label>
  <input id="phone"  name="telf" type="number"  min="111111111" max="999999999" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" size="20" type="email" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro... por favor agrega aquí el código (editar tu respuesta)... te recomiendo hacer el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ver las [ayudas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) de este sitio.. saludos

Comment: Alejandro, deberías agregar el código, sino te eliminarán la respuesta, por ser de baja calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo podrías hacer validando los campos al hacer el submit del formulario. Deberías añadir la propiedad `onsubmit="return validar()"` al tag del `form` en primer lugar y la funcion `validar()` podría ser algo así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validar() {
  var ok = true;
  var msg = "Debe informar el telefono o el email!";
  if(document.form.inputTelf.value == "" && document.form.inputEmail.value == "")
  {
    ok = false;
  }

  if(ok == false)
    alert(msg);
  return ok;
}
</script>
```

Comment: si, lo que decia en el comentario (pero fui muy vago para programar xDD)